# How to check if two or more elements are colliding in JavaFx layout

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, graphics, observable

I made this simple email client, but it has a problem: When I set the elements into the `AnchorPane` it only sets the last one, so I think that there is a problem of wrong measures. I checked it more than one time, but as you can see the elements are well separated:
[image: mailbox]

This is how I put the elements into the Anchor Pane:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader listLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("lista.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader textareaLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textarea.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader fieldLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("textfield.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader menuLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("menubar.fxml"));
    FXMLLoader buttonLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("button.fxml"));

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(listLoader.load(), textareaLoader.load(), fieldLoader.load(), menuLoader.load(), buttonLoader.load());
```

And these are the FXML files with all the coordinates:

### List.fxml

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.ListController">
    <children>
        <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="239.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### MenuBar

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="mailbox.MenuBarController">
    <children>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0">
            <menus>
                <Menu text="File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem onAction="#elimina" text="Elimina" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu text="Cambia Account">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="email1" text="filippo@hotmail.it" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="email2" text="giancarlo@yahoo.it" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="email3" text="alessandro@gmail.it" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### TextArea

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="mailbox.TextAreaController">
   <children>
           <TextArea fx:id="textarea" editable="false" layoutX="240.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="144.0" prefWidth="360.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### TextField

```xml
<AnchorPane mouseTransparent="false" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.TextFieldController">
   <children>
       <TextField fx:id="id" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="39.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="35.0" />
       <TextField fx:id="mitt" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="72.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="182.0" />
       <TextField fx:id="dest" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="108.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="182.0" />
       <TextField fx:id="oggetto" editable="false" layoutX="355.0" layoutY="144.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="182.0" />
       <TextField fx:id="data" editable="false" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="39.0" mouseTransparent="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <Label layoutX="329.0" layoutY="44.0" text="ID:" />
      <Label layoutX="291.0" layoutY="77.0" text="Mittente:" />
      <Label layoutX="398.0" layoutY="44.0" text="Data:" />
      <Label layoutX="268.0" layoutY="113.0" text="Destinatario:" />
      <Label layoutX="292.0" layoutY="149.0" text="Oggetto:" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

### Button

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.ButtonController">
   <children>
      <Button id="scrivi" layoutX="268.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Scrivi" />
      <Button id="reply" layoutX="342.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Reply" />
      <Button id="replyall" layoutX="420.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Reply-All" />
      <Button id="forward" layoutX="511.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Forward" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You are doing way too much manual work with your layout! You should look into other JavaFX containers (like `BorderPane`, `VBox`, `HBox`, etc). By mixing those containers, you can very easily create simple (or complex) layouts without having to manually control each node's placement.

Comment: What do you mean by _it only sets the last one_?

Comment: @Gnas even if you see them graphically, you can only click with the mouse on the last one.

Comment: @Zephyr but if I create a border pane and then insert all the elements inside, I cannot use more controller like I'm doing now, right? Because I would like to manage it separately

Comment: You definitely do not need (or **want**) a separate controller for every node in a scene. That kind of structure will become absolutely insane as your project grows and very difficult to manage. Generally, you should have one controller class per scene, which handles the logic for all the buttons, text boxes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blue represents AnchorPane of button.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQxGw.png)

I added a blue background color to the `button.fxml` `AnchorPane` .

The problem is the `layoutX` and `layoutY` of the buttons; the co-ordinates of the buttons are calculated with respect to the top left corner of enclosing `AnchorPane` of `button.fxml` and not with respect to `AnchorPane` of `list.xml`. This causes `AnchorPane` to hide the components behind it (as seen by the blue color) and hence the mouse input events are consumed by the `AnchorPane`.

To solve the problem (there are better ways to layout than this, just an adhoc fix) use this code in `button.fxml`

```
<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: blue;" layoutX="268.0" layoutY="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mailbox.ButtonController">
    <HBox><children>
        <Button id="scrivi" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Scrivi" />
        <Button id="reply"  mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Reply" />
        <Button id="replyall"  mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Reply-All" />
        <Button id="forward"  mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Forward" />
    </children>
    </HBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

The above code will start laying out your buttons from where you expected and to make things simple I wrapped them in a Vbox.

As for the checking of collision of 2 nodes use this

```
public static boolean isCollide(Node x, Node y){
            Bounds RectA = x.localToScene(x.getBoundsInLocal());
            Bounds RectB = y.localToScene(y.getBoundsInLocal());

            return RectB.intersects(RectA);
}
```